# MySQL - Query returning non-matching rows

Tags: mysql, join

I am doing a join a some tables and want the result filtered on basis on an ENUM column in a table, which has values 0,1.

Here is the query.

```
SELECT dpc.`id` AS parent_id, 
    dpc.`name` AS parent_name,
    cp.`id` AS child_id, 
    cp.`name` AS child_name,
    cp.`stub` AS stub,
    cp.`active` AS active,
    caf.`aspect_id` AS aspect_id,
    am.`name` AS aspects,
    GROUP_CONCAT( nfw.`aspect_values`) AS aspect_childs
FROM `category_parent` AS cp
JOIN `deals_parent_cat` AS dpc ON cp.`parent_id` = dpc.`id`
JOIN `category_aspect_filters` AS caf ON caf.`cat_id` = cp.`id`
JOIN `aspect_master` AS am ON am.`id` = caf.`aspect_id`
LEFT JOIN `navigation_filters_weightage` AS nfw ON nfw.`cat_id`= cp.`id`
AND nfw.`aspect_id` = am.`id` AND cp.`active`="1"
    GROUP BY parent_id,child_id,aspect_id
    ORDER BY parent_name,cp.`order`,aspects
```

I have put the condition in the query to return only those results which have `cp.active="1"`, still i am getting columns which have a value "0".

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Can you please help with what may be wrong in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query

```
AND nfw.`aspect_id` = am.`id` AND cp.`active`="1"
```

maybe try this one

```
where nfw.`aspect_id` = am.`id` AND cp.`active`="1"
```

Comment: It did not completely solve it (grouped all results into one), but helped towards the solution. Thanks

Comment: update your question..post your result and post what do you want to achieve